# VSCode IntelliSense cannot understand CMake add_definitions

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, vscode-extensions

VSCode IntelliSense cannot understand CMake add_definitions.

What can I do for this.

When I use add_definitions in CMakeList.txt.

```
add_definitions(-DTEST_READING_DEV_ID)
```

In c file I use

```
#ifdef TEST_READING_DEV_ID
...
...
#endif
```

The code block looks like grey.

Comment: Don't use `add_definitions`. It is deprecated. Use `target_compile_definitions` instead and do not put `-D`, which is not needed. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html

Comment: I use target_compile_definitions. But the code block still looks like grey.

Comment: "VSCode IntelliSense cannot understand CMake add_definitions." => there is no C++ syntax highlighting by default. Explain which extensions you rely on for C/C++ syntax highlighting (C/C++ or clangd extensions), if you are also using something like CMake Tools extension to feed syntax highlighting with a `compile_commands.json`, and how you have configured everything to wire all these tools together.

Answer (score 5):

Use cmake generate file `compile_commands.json`. Add this in `CMakeList.txt`

```
target_compile_definitions(app PRIVATE CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1)
```

Build the project.

Add the file `compile_commands.json` to VSCode Extension settings file `c_cpp_properties.json`.

```
"compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json"
```

This article explains the scheme for the c_cpp_properties.json settings file.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference

Now, the code block is not grey.

Comment: Note from [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html): "_This option is implemented only by Makefile Generators and Ninja Generators. It is ignored on other generators._"

Comment: Note: there is also the option to set this option variable on the commandline in the configure command via [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D), or in a preset via a CMakePreset.json file.

Comment: Passing it as an option to `target_compile_definitions` didn't work for me. Using the `variable_watch` I saw where `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` was getting accessed during the build. Only when I explicitly set it to `True` before `add_library` or `add_executable`, it worked.